# I am getting the error multiple times when I click on the submit button more than once

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate the form using javascript. When the input fields are empty, I want the error message to show up next to the corresponding labels. I was able to achieve that but I am getting the error multiple times when I click on the submit button more than once.I want the error to show just one time even when I click on the submit button more than once.

I tried using the if/else to check if the error element already exists.

```js
//form validation

let formEl = document.getElementById('myForm');
let formInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
//let submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
let error = document.getElementById('error');


formEl.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  for (let i = 0; i < formInput.length; i++) {
    let errorEl = document.createElement('SPAN');
    errorEl.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + formInput[i].name + ' is missing';
    errorEl.setAttribute("style", "color: red; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;");

    if (formInput[i].value == '') {

      formInput[i].before(errorEl);
      formInput[i].setAttribute('style', "border: 1px solid red;");

    } else {
      formInput[i].before();

    }
  }

}, true);
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First Name:  <input type="text" id="fname" name="first name"></label>
  <label for="lname">Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="last name"></label>
  <label for="fname">Email: <input type="email" id="email" name="email"></label>
  <label for="phone">Phone: <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"></label>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

the errors are showing multiple times
[image: the errors are showing multiple times]

Comment: You know, you can just add the `required` attribute to the inputs and get HTML5 validation for free. No need to use JavaScript for this here :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required

Comment: Stop creating and adding a new <span> every time - make it once then just hide/show it.

Comment: You are adding it multiple times. Try keeping an error span already. change it's text when you want to update. (replace, instead of appending).

Comment: You might want to disable the submit button on click and re-enable it if the user updates the contents of any form field. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I know I could have just used HTML5 required attribute but I wanted to validate the form solely using plain JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styling I added is purely for the sake of this example. I did, however, add a class "error" to the error elements to make them easily identifiable when checking for their existence (so we don't remove any other elements by accident should the markup change in the future, as opposed to using `span` as a selector or even something like `previousElementSibling()`.).

Now we can check if an error element already exists, and only add a new one if it doesn't. I also added the removal of the error message and the reset of the border color once the field is not empty anymore.

Note: `closest()` is not supported in Internet Explorer, so if you need to support that, you'll need to find a workaround/polyfill for that.

```js
//form validation

let formEl = document.getElementById('myForm');
let formInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
//let submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
let error = document.getElementById('error');


formEl.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  for (let i = 0; i < formInput.length; i++) {
    var prevSibling = formInput[i].previousElementSibling;
    var label = formInput[i].closest('label');
    var hasError = label.querySelector('.error');

    if (formInput[i].value == '') {
      if (!hasError) {
        let errorEl = document.createElement('SPAN');
        errorEl.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + formInput[i].name + ' is missing';
        errorEl.setAttribute("style", "color: red; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;");
        errorEl.className = 'error';
        formInput[i].before(errorEl);
        formInput[i].setAttribute('style', "border: 1px solid red;");
      }
    } else if (hasError) {
      prevSibling.parentElement.removeChild(prevSibling);
      formInput[i].style.border = '';
    }
  }

}, true);
```

```css
label,
input,
.error {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First Name:  <input type="text" id="fname" name="first name"></label>
  <label for="lname">Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="last name"></label>
  <label for="fname">Email: <input type="email" id="email" name="email"></label>
  <label for="phone">Phone: <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"></label>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```